# Laziness in recursive function composition

Tags: haskell, recursion, lazy-evaluation, function-composition

I am trying to understand the lazy evaluation of Haskell and made the following attempt in `GHCi`

```
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :set +m
Prelude> let iterateUntilError1 :: (a->a) -> (a->a)
Prelude|     iterateUntilError1 f = (iterateUntilError1 f) . f
Prelude| 
Prelude> let iterateUntilError2 :: (a->a) -> (a->a)
Prelude|     iterateUntilError2 f = \x -> (iterateUntilError2 f) . f $ x
Prelude| 
Prelude> let iterateUntilError3 :: (a->a) -> (a->a)
Prelude|     iterateUntilError3 f = \x -> (iterateUntilError3 f) . f $! x
Prelude| 
Prelude> let iterateUntilError4 x = foldl1 (.) (repeat (($!) x))
Prelude> iterateUntilError3 tail [1..5]
*** Exception: Prelude.tail: empty list
Prelude> iterate tail [1..5]
[[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5],[4,5],[5],[],*** Exception: Prelude.tail: empty list
```

Among the 4 versions presented, only `iterateUntilError3` works as expected, the other 3 versions enter an infinite loop that has to be stopped via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. I don't quite understand why the other three versions don't work in this case.

The related question [laziness and function composition (haskell, erlang)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032295/laziness-and-function-composition-haskell-erlang) does not seem to address the issues presented in this question.

Comment: After various attempts, I found `flip (foldl' (&)) (repeat x)` with `(&)` from `Data.Function` to be a working version with `fold*` and friends.

Comment: yes, because `z & x = x $ z` and `foldl'` is forcing the accumulator value as it goes along the list, that is equivalent to `flip (foldl' (&)) (repeat x) z = foldl' (&) z (repeat x) = let {z1 = x $! z} in foldl' (&) z1 (repeat x) = let {z1 = x $! z} in let {z2 = x $! z1} in foldl' (&) z2 (repeat x) = ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with `iterateUntilError1`. If you try to evaluate

```
iterateUntilError1 tail [1..5] =
```

expand definition of `iterateUntilError1`:

```
((iterateUntilError1 tail) . tail) [1..5] =
```

expand definition of `.`:

```
(iterateUntilError1 tail) (tail [1..5]) =
```

wait, we have `iterateUntilError1 tail` again!

```
((iterateUntilError1 tail) . tail) (tail [1..5]) =
(iterateUntilError1 tail) (tail (tail [1..5]))
```

and so on.

With `iterateUntilError3` you have (inserting some extra parentheses to make priority more clear)

```
iterateUntilError3 tail [1..5] =
((iterateUntilError3 tail) . tail) $! [1..5] =
((iterateUntilError3 tail) . tail) (1:[2..5]) = 
iterateUntilError3 tail (tail (1:[2..5])) =
(iterateUntilError3 tail . tail) $! (tail (1:[2..5])) =
(iterateUntilError3 tail . tail) (2:[3..5]) = ...
```

and so it ends up getting an error.

With `iterateUntilError2`, you have similar evaluation until the line before last where `$!` forces `tail` to reduce until getting a constructor and `$` doesn't:

```
(iterateUntilError2 tail . tail) $ (tail [1..5]) =
(iterateUntilError2 tail . tail) (tail [1..5]) =
(iterateUntilError2 tail) (tail (tail [1..5])) = ...
```

And finally (using `tail_` for `(tail $!)` for simplicity):

```
iterateUntilError4 tail [1..5] =
foldl1 (.) (repeat tail_) [1..5] = 
foldl (.) tail_ (repeat tail_) [1..5] =
foldl (.) (tail_ . tail_) (repeat tail_) [1..5] =
foldl (.) (tail_ . tail_ . tail_) (repeat tail_) [1..5] = ...
```

(for this one I didn't follow [the actual definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#foldl) but the idea should still be right, I think).

Comment: the actual definition is just an implementation of the equation specification above it, so it's all good.